# How to make bluetooth headphones and keyboard play nicely?

Tags: keyboard, audio, bluetooth, headphones

I have a Jabra Move bluetooth headset and a bluetooth Apple Magic Keyboard circa 2010/2011.

I can pair them both with my 2015 Mac Book Pro (running OS X Sierra) with ease. However, as soon as I start playing audio through my Mac to the headphones one or both of two things happens:

1) The music drops in and out

and/or, *worse*

2) The keyboard disconnects and reconnects frequently.

It's so frustrating that I mainly disconnect my headphones from my mac and stream music through from my phone.

I used to have the same setup with a ~2013 Mac Mini and had *exactly* the same problem.

I am in a busy office full of computers, phones and bluetooth and wireless devices.

Answer (score 1):

Problem: This could be caused by interference from the volume of bluetooth connections being used all around you. Macs are supposed to have support for up to 7 devices. However, your headphones COULD be using up multiple bluetooth connections. Mono headphones use 1 port, Stereo headphones use 2 ports, 5.1 channel surround sound headphones (if they exist) use 6 ports. Your headphones could potentially be kicking the keyboard off, or not connecting because the keyboard is using 1 bluetooth port, disabling the headphones from using all the ports they want.
Since you're using a headset, you could have stereo input AND output, using 4 bluetooth ports.

Solution: Use a cheaper headset, USB keyboard, 3.5mm headset, or contact Apple Support. Only they can help you if my solutions aren't satisfactory.

Other things that could potentially help:
Resetting PRAM.
Restarting your Mac.
Checking your bluetooth settings. (Your Mac may be connecting to other peoples devices)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Apple support cannot help with design flaws in apple products. The broadcom chips they use are horrible.

Answer (score 1):

What if you go away from Wi-Fi noise? The 39 bluetooth channels are splattered by the same spectrum as Wi-Fi - particularly the >=300Mbit/s 802.11n stuff and later will trip you up. It is definitely not bluetooth noise, however, as it runs the gamut from 1mW to 20mW, with most devices using 5-10mW.

Resetting PRAM will not help you.

I have used several discreet bluetooth dongles to each handle bluetooth connections. With my macbook pro, bluetooth was weak, despite not being behind alu-casing (IIRC its antenna is at the top of the screen), so I used a few in USB ports. Problem went away forever.